# How to generate Swagger 1.2 JSON with .NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

We're trying to generate Swagger 1.2 spec JSON for our .NET Web API. I've tried using Swashbuckle, but it only seems to generate Swagger 2.0 spec JSON.

Does anyone know how to generate Swagger 1.2 JSON from a .NET Web API (using Swashbuckle or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why you want to use Swagger 1.2 over Swagger 2.0, but you can still use Swashbuckle, only an older version of it such as https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/tree/v4.2.0.

Comment: Thanks Ron. We're using 3Scale for API management, and their documentation module requires Swagger but doesn't support 2.0.

Comment: I believe they should add support for it pretty soon, and migrating from 1.2 to 2.0 using a library shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a stand-alone/cli parser that can scan .net classes and then generate the json files(s), without the need for me to add a package into the project

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

This swagger.json file can be generated as an ouput of the project build, using swagger. In your webApi .csproj file, add this section:

```
<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe) webapi2swagger /infotitle:&quot;$(AssemblyName)&quot; /assembly:$(TargetPath) /output:$(OutDir)/$(AssemblyName).swagger.json" />
  </Target>
```

You also need to attribute your API controller methods like this, e.g.:
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(object))]